# define a special org-link face inside of org-table, different from outside?

Tags: org-mode, faces, fonts, org-table, org-link

I'd like to define a special `org-link` face inside of org tables, such as to set link to fixed fonts within a table, and to variable fonts outside. I tried to play with `custom-theme-set-faces` in various ways without any success.

I've the feeling the answer should define somehow a conditional rule checking whether or not a face (here a link) is within a table or outside. But this is maybe incompatible with the way `custom-theme-set-faces` works?

Also, I'd like to not rely on another package such as `valign` (nothing against it, it's just that my wish is to get something simple).

I found a couple of older related posts on `emacs.stackexchange` but none seem to provide a definitive answer, or maybe I missed them.

Any clues on this matter would help. Thank you.